# yii2 add model data to chart

Tags: charts, yii2

I'm trying to use [Yii2 HighChart Widgets](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-highcharts-widget) with my data from model.

This is my example view:

```
<?= \dosamigos\highcharts\HighCharts::widget([
    'clientOptions' => [
        'chart' => [
                'type' => 'bar'
        ],
        'title' => [
             'text' => 'Fruit Consumption'
             ],
         'xAxis' => [
            'type' => 'datetime',

        ],
        'yAxis' => [
            'title' => [
                'text' => 'Fruit eaten'
            ]
        ],
        'series' => [
            ['name' => 'Jane', 'data' => [1, 0, 4]],
            ['name' => 'John', 'data' => [5, 7, 3]]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

- How can I insert my data from model to series?
- I change my  xAxis to
  datetime but how can I add date create to my series data?

Comment: check this link, http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-from-a-database hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks, now I can add data from my table but how can I add the time data?

Comment: yes, now I understand how to add time)